# Sequelize Typescript: Type 'FavoriteEntity[]' is not assignable to type 'FavoriteEntity | null'

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs

I'm writing a NestJS application using Sequelize-Typescript as ORM.

Here I'm trying to get a users favorited jobs (M:M) and so I have a UserEntity, a JobEntity (not relevant for this question) and a FavoriteEntity.

> favorite.entity.ts

```
import { Table, Column, Model, PrimaryKey, ForeignKey, BelongsTo, NotNull } from "sequelize-typescript";
import { IDefineOptions } from "sequelize-typescript/lib/interfaces/IDefineOptions";
import { UserEntity } from "../users/user.entity";
import { JobEntity } from "../jobs/job.entity";

const tableOptions: IDefineOptions = {
  timestamp: true,
  tableName: "favorites",
  schema: process.env.DB_SCHEMA,
} as IDefineOptions;

@Table(tableOptions)
export class FavoriteEntity extends Model<FavoriteEntity> {
  @BelongsTo(() => UserEntity)
  user: UserEntity;

  @ForeignKey(() => UserEntity)
  @PrimaryKey
  @NotNull
  @Column
  userId: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => JobEntity)
  job: JobEntity;

  @ForeignKey(() => JobEntity)
  @PrimaryKey
  @NotNull
  @Column
  jobId: number;
}
```

> favorite.service.ts

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Model } from "sequelize-typescript";
import { IFavorite, IFavoriteService } from "./interfaces";
import { FavoriteEntity } from "./favorite.entity";

@Injectable()
export class FavoriteService implements IFavoriteService {
  constructor(
    @Inject("FavoriteRepository") private readonly favoriteRepository: typeof Model,
    @Inject("SequelizeInstance") private readonly sequelizeInstance,
  ) {}

  public async findByUserId(userId: number): Promise<FavoriteEntity | null> {
    return await FavoriteEntity.scope().findAll<FavoriteEntity>({
      where: { userId },
    });
  }
}
```

I'm getting a type error that I really don't understand:

> TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
>   src/modules/favorite/favorite.service.ts(21,5): error TS2322: Type
>   'FavoriteEntity[]' is not assignable to type 'FavoriteEntity | null'. 
>   Type 'FavoriteEntity[]' is not assignable to type 'FavoriteEntity'.
>       Property 'user' is missing in type 'FavoriteEntity[]'.

I don't understand why it's complaining about a missing `user`, it's clearly there. (If I make it optional (?) in the entity it complains about the next property until I make them all optional, and then It's complaining about a missing property dataValues in the same way)

What am I missing?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
So I might have figured out something. If I write like this

```
return await FavoriteEntity.scope().findAll<FavoriteEntity[]>({
  where: { userId },
});
```

with `FavoriteEntity[]` instead of `FavoriteEntity`, I get

> Property 'dataValues' is missing in type 'FavoriteEntity[]'

I don't really know which is the correct way to write it, but I still have a problem either way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAll` will return an array of entities. You only want one or null. For that, use `findOne`. Also, you don't need to do `return await` here. Unless in a try-catch block, this is redundant.

Comment: Yup I think I just figured that out too. Which means I have to update my typings to reflect that it's returning an array. When I fix the interface it's not complaining anymore... Thanks!

Comment: Aha, I didn't know about the await-return. Thanks again!